# LAN to WAN or LAN to LAN repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, wired-networking, repeater, wired

I find a lot of tutorial how to set up repeater but this will not work, because signal between main router and router that I want to make a repeater is poor.

I have been using second router as different network wired with main router, but I am tired of switching networks while I go downstairs/upstairs of my house.

I am not 100% new at this and I know a bit but I just don't know how to do it, whatever I try I run in to problems, that makes my slave router not working properly, especially WiFi.

I would like for someone to help me with this, telling me just basic steps of what should I do to make second router a repeater but in wired mode.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the router as just an access point and switch. Disable its DHCP server. Disable its WAN port. Set its IP LAN address to an IP address inside the main router's LAN but outside its DHCP range. Connect a LAN port on one router to a LAN port on the other router. Configure the SSID and WiFi encryption the same. You can use different channels.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this. Set it up as a normal repeater.

Then connect an ethernet cord from the LAN port of the BaseStation to the LAN port (I could be mistaken here, it might be the WAN port you want) of the Repeater.

I've done it before, and it cut down internal network packet loss to 0%. I.e., from any laptop pinging the cable modem, the packet loss was 0%.